# EF Code First not returning related objects

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF Code First with a pre-existing database.

Two objects:

```
public Foo
{
    public int FooId {get;set;}
}

public Bar
{
    public int BarId {get;set;}
    public virtual Foo Foo {get;set;}
}
```

Both `FooId` and `BarId` are primary keys in the database, and the `Bar` table has a column `FooId` which is a foreign key pointing at the `Foo` table.

When I select a `Bar`, `Foo` is a null reference.  I would have thought EF would have automatically pulled the two of them together, but perhaps I'm missing something?

Database mappings:

```
public class EFCodeFirst : DbContext
{
    public EFCodeFirst()
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AlternateString"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public DBSet<Foo> Foos {get;set;}
    public DBSet<Bar> Bars {get;set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.IncludeMetadataInDatabase = false;
        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().MapSingleType().ToTable("Foo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().MapSingleType().ToTable("Bar");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your code first mapping? What happens if you call the query with Include("Foo")?

Comment: If I `Include("Foo")` it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your expectation of Foo should not be null is coming from the fact that you make it *virtual* on Bar object, then that's not the case. By make them virtual, you just opt in to EF lazy loading and it will be null up until to the point that you explicitly ask for it by accessing it on Bar object. Other than that, if you want it to be populated upfront you would have to eager load it with *Include* method.

To explicitly disable lazy loading you can use the following code, even though you don't need it since you can just remove the *virtual* keyword from your navigation properties and lazy loading would be gone.

```
public EFCodeFirst()
{        
    this.ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

Internally, DbContext uses a *protected* ObjectContext that you can also use inside your inherited DbContext class (e.g. EFCodeFirst).

Comment: But either way it should still resolve, correct?  Either with an early or later call to the DB.

Comment: I also cannot figure when to disable lazy loading.  None of the objects have a reference to `ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled`.

Comment: Yes that is correct and it does work. You need to show us the code that does not work.

Comment: I also edit my answer to show how to change the value of  `ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a line in the Foo class, that Foo contains a collection of Bar.

Comment: There is currently no need to access the Bar objects from the parent Foo.

Comment: Yes, but that is what tells EF to make the relationship, not having it gives you the null reference exception